# actionscript3 rss feed scrolling text

Tags: actionscript

I am new to actionscript3 and I have a noobish question, if someone can help me that would be very helpful. I am trying to do an actionscript that reads from a rss feed xml file and display it in a text box and make the box scroll automatically, my problem is the text field doesn't loop back. here is the code:

```
var RSSLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
var RSSURL:URLRequest = new URLRequest("http://sports.yahoo.com/soccer//rss.xml");
RSSLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, RSSLoaded);
RSSLoader.load(RSSURL);
stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, TextScrollingFunction);

var RSSXML:XML = new XML();

RSSXML.ignoreWhitespace = true;

function RSSLoaded(e:Event):void 

 {

RSSXML = XML(RSSLoader.data);
//trace(RSSXML.toXMLString());
var title:TextField;
var desc:TextField;
var allText:TextField;
title = new TextField();
allText = new TextField();
for(var selectedItems:String in RSSXML.channel.item){

    title.text=(RSSXML.channel.item[selectedItems].title+"\n");
    title.wordWrap = true;
    tfLog.text+=title.text;
    tfLog.wordWrap = true;
    trace(title.text);

}

function TextScrollingFunction(evt:Event)

{

tfLog.x+=3;//the Speed of the srolling Text

if ((tfLog.x + tfLog.width)<0) {
    tfLog.x=stage.stageWidth;

    //remove all the Children from the stage.
    while (tfLog.numChildren > 0) {
        tfLog.removeChildAt(0);
    }
    RSSLoader.load(RSSURL);
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much sir, much appreciated. I deleted that function and created a timer that deletes each letter in the text.

Answer (score 0):

If every loader things work normally, I would like to say the problem is likely to be :

```
...
if (tfLog.x > stage.stageWidth) {
    tfLog.x = -tfLog.width;   //but in case your textfield has a static width
...
```

Or Simply:

```
...
tfLog.x -= 3;
...
```